# Forgerock: Message when trying to start OpenDJ after reinstallation

Tags: openam, opendj, forgerock

After opendj installation. 
run ./start-ds

```
The Directory Server could not acquire an exclusive lock on file /Space/Tests/XX/opendj/locks/server.lock: 
The attempt to obtain an exclusive lock on file /Space/Tests/XX/opendj/locks/server.lock was rejected 
because the attempt to create the lock file failed: 
IOException(No such file or directory). This generally means that another instance of this server is already running
```

opendj: **2.6.0** 
openam: **12.0.0**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using embedded OpenDJ, then stop the OpenAM deployment container and remove the 'lock' file. You may then just start the 'embedded' OpenDJ as standalone and stop it again to make sure it can be started in the 'embedded' way when OpenAM deployment container is started.